# I need suggestions for large-scale web site

Tags: database, postgresql, joomla, high-traffic

I am planning a social networking and magazine website for university students. It is expected to have 200.000 members in a year and high/traffic. I am planning to use Joomla and it is extensions. Jomsocial, EasyBlog, EasyDiscuss, Reviews for Joomla and Zoo are the extension to install. Here is my questions.

What DB should i use? > Monge > PostgreSQL, MySQL etc.
What should i do to handle large amount of data read/write?
What kind of extensions should PHP and SERVER have?

Regards

Comment: Closed soon enough, but - use what you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to turn my comments into an answer.  But first a disclosure:  I don't know anything about Joomla.

As has been said before, do whatever is easiest and quickest (within reason). Don't dwell on questions that are most likely irrelevant (i.e your site is not likely to meet your goals).

Having said that, the biggest question is indeed SQL vs noSQL.  If everything is interconnected and you cannot scale horizontally by adding unconnected databases, then noSQL may be something to consider.  There are many threads on that topic.  And a new arrival on the noSQL scene is Amazon's DynamoDB (hosted, managed).